# How to call Button_Click from Ribon-Class in c# Office Add-in?

Tags: c#, button, visio, office-addins, ribbon-control

I'm working on an Office-Add in for Microsoft Visio. I am starting my Application by Clicking on a Button of the Ribbon-Control in MS Office. My problem is, that at a certain Point I want to call a `StopButton_Click` Method located in the `Ribbon-Class` (just like the Start-Button, clicked earlier) from another class `Class2`. However this is not possible without creating another instance of the `Ribbon-Class` in `Class2` to which I refer by calling the `StopButton_Click`.
Right now, my code looks like this:

```
public partial class Ribbon {
     public void StopButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
     {
          //Button to Stop Application
          //enable/disable Ribbon Control Buttons
     }
}


static class Class2 {
     //some Code
     Ribbon r = new Ribbon();
     r.StopButton_Click;
     // some more code
}
```

In the `StopButton_Click` Method I am enabling/disabling certain Buttons of the Ribbon-Control of MS Office (depending on whether the app is started or stopped).The Problem now is, that the Application Stops, but the Buttons in the Ribbon-Control are not changing. I think it's because I am calling the `StopButton_Click` on another Instance than the one I started the Application.

Is there a solution for this? Like calling the `StopButton_Click` in `Class2` without creating another Instance?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: First create a `public` property of `Ribbon-Class` inside the class in which you want to access the `StopButton`. Then pass the reference to it. Thus you can access it using `myproperty.StopButton_Click(sender, e);`

Comment: @Nobody am I not already doing this by `Ribbon r = new Ribbon()` ? Or, if i am wrong, can you provide a small example maybe? thank you

Comment: Sorry, lemme rephrase what i said. Create a property of `Ribbon-Class` in a static class(let's say `Globals`) which can be accessed from anywhere in the program. Pass this reference while initiating the app for the first time. `Globals.RibbonProperty = r;`. If you are not disposing this object, then you can now access it as `Globals.RibbonProperty.StopButton_Click(sender, e);`